# WHERE condition with alias not working

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause

I have a query like this

```
SELECT 
table1.question_id,
SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer = 1, 1, 0)) AS correct_answers,
SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer != 1, 1, 0)) AS incorrect_answers,
round((SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer = 1, 1, 0)) / (SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer = 1, 1, 0)) + SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer != 1, 1, 0))) * 100),
        2) AS percentage
FROM
    table2
        JOIN
    table1 ON table2.answer_id = table1.id
WHERE
    percentage BETWEEN 10 AND 20
group by table1.question_id;
```

I am trying to fetch the question_id, number of correct answers, number of incorrect answers, and correct percentage WHERE the the percentage between certain value. Now everything is working other than the where part. It is showing unknown column 'percentage'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only are column aliases not allowed in a `where` clause, but the logic you want requires a `having` clause.  This is on an *aggregated* result:

```
SELECT table1.question_id,
       SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer = 1, 1, 0)) AS correct_answers,
       SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer != 1, 1, 0)) AS incorrect_answers,
       round((SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer = 1, 1, 0)) / (SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer = 1, 1, 0)) + SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer != 1, 1, 0))) * 100),
             2) AS percentage
FROM table2 JOIN
     table1
     ON table2.answer_id = table1.id
group by table1.question_id
HAVING percentage BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter on results of aggregate function you need to use `HAVING` clause,`WHERE` filter will not work in this scenario,if you still want to do it with where then you have to repeat the whole expression in where clause

```
SELECT 
  table1.question_id,
  SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer = 1, 1, 0)) AS correct_answers,
  SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer != 1, 1, 0)) AS incorrect_answers,
  ROUND(
    (
      SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer = 1, 1, 0)) / (
        SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer = 1, 1, 0)) + SUM(IF(table1.correct_answer != 1, 1, 0))
      ) * 100
    ),
    2
  ) AS percentage 
FROM
  table2 
  JOIN table1 
    ON table2.answer_id = table1.id 
GROUP BY table1.question_id 
HAVING percentage BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```